# How to sort dictionary high to low and alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, alphabetical, key-value-store

I have tried to sort my array from high to low however using advice from this website i could only sort it from low to high and couldn't sort alphabetically.

My code:

```
x={"luiz":2,"adrian":8,"guv":10,"homer":3,"jane":6}

y={"gus":3,"gump":7,"harry":7,"elliot":9}

z={"elizabeth":10,"micheal":2,"david":7}

sorted_x = sorted(x.items() , key operator.itemgetter(1))

sorted_y = sorted(x.items() , key operator.itemgetter(1))

sorted_z = sorted(x.items() , key operator.itemgetter(1))
```

my program needs to output the name and values from highest score to lowest and then output the dictionarys alphabetically

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: im pretty sure the second argument to all the sorted functions is a syntax error. @Cyber but he is creating a list of items which is orderable

Comment: @Cyber: but their output is a sorted list of key-value pairs.

Comment: Where are your `=` characters? They are required in your `sorted()` calls.

Comment: So what is your expected output? What should be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: sorted_x = sorted(x.items() , key=operator.itemgetter(1))

Comment: Presumably you want `sorted_y` and `sorted_z` to be on `y.items()` and `z.items()`, respectively?  Looks like a copy-paste mistake, in addition to the fixes needed as described by @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the sort, simply add `reverse=True`:

```
sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Presumably you wanted to sort the *keys* alphabetically, rather than sort by score from lowest to highest; in that case just *omit the key*:

```
sorted(x.items())
```

because the key-vale tuples produced by `dict.items()` are already going to be sorted by the key first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this is my program now

```
import operator

x={"luiz":2,"adrian":8,"guv":10,"homer":3,"jane":6}

sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

sorted(x.items())
y={"gus":3,"gump":7,"harry":7,"elliot":9}

sorted(y.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

sorted(y.items())

z={"elizabeth":10,"micheal":2,"david":7}

sorted(z.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

sorted(z.items())
```